# Getting jobs from beanstalkd - timed out exception

Tags: python, timeout, jobs, beanstalkd, beanstalkc

I am using `Python 2.7`, `beanstalkd server` with  `beanstalkc` as the client library.

It takes about 500 to 1500 ms to process each job, depending on the size of the job.

I have a `cron` job that will keep adding jobs to the beanstalkd queue and a "worker" that will run in an infinite loop getting jobs and processing them.

eg:

```
def get_job(self):
    while True:
        job = self.beanstalk.reserve(timeout=0)
        if job is None:
            timeout = 10 #seconds
            continue
        else:
            timeout = 0 #seconds
            self.process_job(job)
```

This results in `"timed out"` exception.

Is this the best practice to pull a job from the queue?

Could someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `beanstalk.reserve(timeout=0)` means to wait 0 seconds for a job to become available,
so it'll time out immediately unless a job is already
in the queue when it's called. If you want it never to time out,
use `timeout=None` (or omit the timeout parameter, since `None` is the default).